# Appium and python: find element child

Tags: python, ios, appium, element

So i have application that i am testing and i have this condition that i have `element` and i want to fine its child.

My `element`:

```
element = elements[0]
```

The child element is `XCUIElementTypeButton` (first child) and this is what i have try:

```
son = element.find_element_by_xpath('/XCUIElementTypeButton')
```

Or

```
son = element.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementTypeButton')
```

So i try both and none of this work and `NoSuchElementException` received.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.` to your XPath query so the scope would be relative to the current element like:

```
son = element.find_element_by_xpath('./XCUIElementTypeButton')
```

or use [`child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/child) axe

```
son = element.find_element_by_xpath('child::XCUIElementTypeButton')
```

or simply go for a wildcard:

```
son = element.find_element_by_xpath('child::*')
```

References:

- [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: Can i also use parent::ElementType ?

Comment: You can, but it will not return the element parent, not the child.

Comment: So in case i want the parent what should i do ?